# Check people's attendance of shared calendar events

Tags: gmail, calendar, google-calendar, events

In a small non-profit group (about 20 people), I have recently become responsible for the calendar, events and communications management, so I am taking a look at their gmail account and looking for optimal ways to manage it. I have experience with gmail and google products but not with the management of small groups like this.

1. I created a mailing list with all the volunteers, so I can e-mail them faster
2. I created a calendar with all their events and shared it to the mailing list; everyone (me included on my personal account) receives it and can add it to their service of choice;
3. I invited everyone to Event A: since members volunteer to participate, I thought this was the best way to keep count of who will attend

However, when I double-check on my personal account I see Event A twice: as a shared calendar event **AND** as a personal event to which I have been invited.

Obviously this is not optimal, because of the calendar clutter and the amount of e-mails I have to send (and receive!).

**Is there a way to have people join/respond/attend an event in a shared calendar without being invited directly?**

Comment: Sorry, we don't deal with specific web sites/apps here. I've voted to migrate your question to the Web Apps Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @BenN I did not know whether this was the right site or not. Thank you for the info.